# Vertical bar in matrix appearing twice

Tags: support, mathjax

$$
    \left(
      \begin{array}{c|c}
        \Huge{a} & \Huge{b} \\
        \hline
        \Huge{c} & \Huge{d}
      \end{array}
    \right)
    \quad
    \left(
      \begin{array}{c|c}
        \Huge{A_{11}} & & \Huge{A_{12}} \\
        \hline
        \Huge{0} & & \Huge{A_{22}}
      \end{array}
    \right)
$$
Exactly *why* does that vertical line appear only once, as it should, on the left, and twice, as it should *not*, on the right?

MathJax code:

```
\left(
  \begin{array}{c|c}
        \Huge{a} & \Huge{b} \\
        \hline
        \Huge{c} & \Huge{d}
      \end{array}
\right)
\quad
\left(
  \begin{array}{c|c}
        \Huge{A_{11}} & & \Huge{A_{12}} \\
        \hline
        \Huge{0} & & \Huge{A_{22}}
      \end{array}
\right)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\Huge{A_{11}} & & \Huge{A_{12}} \\
```

You have included two ampersands instead of one, implicitly creating three columns.  But earlier, you specified only two columns: `{c|c}`.  This is causing MathJax to behave oddly.

This raises an error when I try it with pdfLaTeX on my laptop, so it is something to do with MathJax.  Use consistent alignment characters (`&`) and you should not run into this problem.

Comment: It was my understanding that LaTeX would extend the column specification for new columns, so I think MathJax is doing the right thing. Is pdfLaTeX raising an error, or a warning?

Comment: It's really an error: "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr." (I know the text sounds like a warning, but it's counted as an error.) It does still produce an output, but by bumping the $A_{12}$ to the first entry of a new row, rather than by adding the third column.